# Google API "games.players.get" returns 500

Tags: google-api, google-api-php-client, google-play-games, google-api-client, google-apis-explorer

I'm trying to get player info for authenticated user, it successful for the first request, but then fails later.

```
{
 "error": {
  "code": 500,
  "message": null
 }
}
```

I already turning on OAuth 2.0, set the playerId to 'me', but it returns 500.
Is there something wrong? Is there any limit requests for this one? Is anything missing?

Thanks,

Comment: could it be that you're access token has expired?

Comment: hmm no, I tried both on Google's APIs Explorer and Google's OAuth 2.0 Playground, it returns same error.

Comment: show more code or parameters

Comment: I only set the playerId parameter to 'me'. Is there any more parameters I needed?

Comment: no idea how you're testing it.

Comment: I tried on [Games Web API Documentation](https://developers.google.com/games/services/web/api/players/get#try-it), [OAuth 2.0 Playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground), and [Google APIs Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/?hl=in#p/games/v1/games.players.get?playerId=me&_h=1&) and they are return same error. I only put "me" on playerID parameter.